# FormData throws Network Error All the time

Tags: node.js, react-native, multer, form-data

I am trying to upload a file to my NodeJs Server from My Mobile ReactNative App.

I tried to use FormData with Axios post but it is resulting in a NetworkError. Logging the FormData object before sending it gives me an object with an Array `_parts` that contains Arrays of my fields.

Also when I console.log the prototypes of FormData I only get two methods that I can use, which are `append` and `getParts`. I can't use any method that does exist in the documentation like `getHeaders` or `getBoundary`

Now If I want to make a file upload without using FormData, Should I send a fileStream of the picture I want to upload or just send the uri of the picture? I am using multer to capture the Files in my server.

Comment: how did you solve it?

Comment: I stringified every embeded object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was causing the Network Error is me using a nested object inside dataForm.

```
//Other code onTop
const {location, ...other} = payload;
form.append("location", JSON.stringify(location));
...
```

I hope this might help someone.

Also Files Are Blobs, basically a readabaleStream. [Read More About it Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)